# Alterar label de um radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho esse `radio button` e gostaria de mudar texto do `radio button` "Todos" para sim, dependendo da condição:

```
  <label id="radiotodos" class="radio-inline control-label">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">Todos
  </label>
```

Porém quando faço assim:

```
  $("#radiotodos").html("Sim");
```

Não funciona, ele muda para sim, mas some o `radiobutton`, já tentei alterando o `id`, porém não dá certo.

Comment: o que voçe pertende fazer ao certo? ao clicar nessa radio button alterar todos os outros radios buttons para SIM?

Comment: Já tentou `$("#radiotodos").text("Sim")`

Comment: Você está pegando o valor do `label`, desta forma não funcionará. Você deverá pegar o valor do `input` e trocar, algo como `$("#firstopt").prop("checked", "true")`. Fazendo desta forma, a opção será marcada.

Comment: @Azzi tentei, porém o `radiobutton` some e fica apenas o sim.

Comment: @Ricardo eu já tenho a condição, eu preciso que quando ele entrar na condição, ele mude o texto para Sim.

Comment: @JaksonFischer eu não marcá-lo, eu quero alterar o label, o texto.

Comment: Ahh, certo, entendi agora... Bom desta forma funcionará como o exemplo do @Ricardo abaixo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente Isto

```
$("#radiotodos").html('<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">Sim');
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, esperando só dar o tempo, para aceitar sua resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: obrigado, feliz por poder ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Como o texto "Todos" é o último nó dentro da label, você pode alterar apenas ele pegando a quantidade de nós -1. Por exemplo, se a label tiver 3 nós, você deve pegar o nó 2 (como numa array, onde os índices começam do 0):

```js
var nos = document.getElementById("radiotodos").childNodes; // pega os nós
nos[nos.length-1].nodeValue = "Sim"; // altera o último nó
```

```html
<label id="radiotodos" class="radio-inline control-label">
   <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">Todos
</label>
```

---

Se tiver usando jQuery, pode fazer desta forma também:

```js
$("#radiotodos").contents().filter(function(){
   return this.textContent.trim() == "Todos";
}).each(function(){
   this.nodeValue = "Sim";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="radiotodos" class="radio-inline control-label">
   <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">Todos
</label>
```